# Hiding iFrame or Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a conditional webpage for detect browser and show div.

I have 5 div with 5 id.

like:

```
<div id="firefox">
     iframe here
</div>

<div id="chrome">
      iframe here
</div>

<div id="ie">
     iframe here
</div>

<div id="opera">
     iframe here
</div>

<div id="safari">
     iframe here
</div>
```

- when I open this webpage from firefox, its show you firefox iframe. and this time body class is "gecko win"
- when I open this webpage from chrome, its show you firefox iframe. and this time body class is "webkit chrome"
- when I open this webpage from safari, its show you firefox iframe. and this time body class is "safari"
- when I open this webpage from IE, its show you firefox iframe. and this time body class is blank.

Now I need a javascript code that ...

- when body class is "gecko win" this time its automatically remove the others div like: chrome, opera, safari .. full content.
- when its use body class "chrome" this time its removed the firefox, ie, opera and others . keep chrome only.

Its possible???

If possible what is the code??

My FULL Code is: http://pastie.org/private/6who43sltqkttc0taoqjug

I don't set display none code. its already works. but I want the code based on html/body class.

- When body/html class is  chrome only show chrome div and remove all others div from page.
- when body/html class is firefox only show firefox div and remove all others div from page.
- when body/html class is blank only show IE div and remove all others div from page.

I don't want to set `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` code. I want to `remove()` javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var browser=*your_method_to_find_browser (serverside or client side)*;
switch (browser)
{
     case 'firefox':
         $("#chrome").css('display','none');
         $("#ie").css('display','none');
         $("#opera").css('display','none');
         $("#safari").css('display','none');
         break;
     case 'chrome':
         $("#firefox").css('display','none');
         $("#ie").css('display','none');
         $("#opera").css('display','none');
         $("#safari").css('display','none');
         break;
     case 'ie':
         $("#chrome").css('display','none');
         $("#firefox").css('display','none');
         $("#opera").css('display','none');
         $("#safari").css('display','none');
         break;
     case 'opera':
         $("#chrome").css('display','none');
         $("#ie").css('display','none');
         $("#firefox").css('display','none');
         $("#safari").css('display','none');
         break;
     case 'safari':
         $("#chrome").css('display','none');
         $("#ie").css('display','none');
         $("#opera").css('display','none');
         $("#firefox").css('display','none');
         break;
}
```

Comment: I am not saying this won't work, but wouldn't it be easier to hide all divs at start (using plain CSS) and then display just the required one rather than writing 4 lines of code under each case?

Comment: @Harry +1. And instead of 4 lines, here, you can do `$("#chrome,#ie,#opera,#firefox").css('display','none');`. But your solution is still better ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
BrowserDetect.init();
```

Let's assume we have a div in place.

```
<div id="userInfo"></div>
```

write out conditional statements for the version/platforms. This is going to be a long list, because unfortunately you need to reverse engineer this code to work as you'd want.

```
var a = BrowserDetect.browser,
b = BrowserDetect.version,
c = BrowserDetect.OS;
if(a == "Firefox" && b >= "14" && c == "Windows"){
    //firefox greater then or equal to 14, on windows
    $("#userInfo").text(a +' '+ b + ' - ' + c);
}else if(a == "Explorer" && b == "9" && c == "Windows"){
    //ie9 on windows
    $("#userInfo").text(a +' - '+ b + ' - ' + c);   
}else if(a == "Chrome" && b > "19" && c == "Mac"){
    //chrome greater than 19 on a mac
    $("#userInfo").text(a +' - '+ b + ' - ' + c); 
}
//more conditionals here
```

In your case remove versions and platforms ..

Comment: A link to that library could really help the OP.